# How can I link to a custom library when building MySQL Server from source?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, cmake

I installed MySQL server using a standard source distribution (mysql-server-8.0) according to this url: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing-source-distribution.html. For some purpose, I added some code to MySQL source code in `mysql-server-8.0/sql/mysqld.cc`, and the code I added used a custom `.so` library in `/usr/lib`.

I want to link to this library when building MySQL source code, so when I built MySQL, I used following commands:

```
cmake .. -DWITH_BOOST=/home/ubuntu/mysql-server-8.0/boost \
         -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCONFIG_CLIENT_LIBS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
         -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-lmy_lib_name -L/usr/lib" \
make
```

Although I tried to add flag when compiling and linking, it failed to complete building, reporting that `error: undefined reference to 'symbols in my library'` . Is there any way to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Shy do the options go before the source dir? They should be added before. Aot sure if cmake does parse this correctly, even if this use is not documented. You could use e.g. `cmake -N -LAH . | grep CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to see, if the values were properly inserted into the cache. If you're modieying the sources anyways, why not add `target_link_libraries` in the correct cmake file though?

Comment: You probably want [`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments! I found that I didn't correctly use C in `.cc` source file. It should be noticed that in `.cc` file C headers should be used like:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "mylib.h"
}
```

So the linking procedure worked fine. The compiler can't identify the function signature because of my misuse of the library headers in `.cc` file.